# c++ QObject's Child Management

Tags: c++, qt4

This question is from a past exam paper and it is used for revision purposes

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QVBoxLayout> 
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QWidget> 

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app (argc, argv);
    QWidget window;

    QLabel* label =  new QLabel("Please enter some text");
    QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit;
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addwidget(label);
    layout->addwidget(textEdit);

    window.setLayout(layout);
    window.show;

    return app.exec();
}
```

1. Qt provides a child management facility through the QObject class. Where is the QObject in the program above? Explain
2. The QObject class provides the function setParent(QObject *parent) to specify a Qbject to be its parent. Why is this function not use in this program?
3. The program uses both heap and stack objects. Explain how the parnt-child facility works when the:

a. parent is a heap obhect and the child objects are stack objects
b.parent is a stack obhect and the child objects are heap objects

Comment: We're not going to do that whole homework assignment for you. What specifically don't you understand? What do you _think_ the answers are and why?

Comment: I do not understand child management facility and heap and stack objects. It is revision not assignment

Comment: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/objecttrees.html explains that, and the Qt docs are pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QObject documentation is available [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html), and can also be accessed via Qt assistant. So go ahead and read it.